# Decoding ico format using BitmapFactory

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap

I am trying to render `.ico` files on image view. But I'm not able to get `Bitmap`. I have pasted code below.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( inputByte, 0, input.length);
```

where the input is byte steam of `.ico` image coming from windows end.
I have observed that `Bitmap` object is getting created but when I printed `height` and `width` , the dimensions are 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap):

> Android supports bitmap files in a three formats: .png
>   (preferred), .jpg (acceptable), .gif (discouraged).

Ok, so that's not the answer you wanted to hear.  Have you considered converting the .ico bytes to another format before pushing it to the device?

The ico file format is [publicly documented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29). You could consider writing code to extract the BMP out of the ico (and manually build a Bitmap from the RGB bytes).  Or if the ico is in png format, you could extract the PNG bytes out directly from the middle of the ico file and then call the appropriate BitmapFactory.decode method.  ico files are a bit different - as they contain several images of different resolutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply selbie. If you could share some documentation that converts .Ico byte array to .png or bmp byte arrays that would be great favour.